# A proton and antiproton annihilate at rest into pions

Tags: homework-and-exercises, particle-physics, nuclear-physics

I'm having a difficult time with this particular problem. I'm really hoping for some guidance.

A proton and an antiproton annihilate at rest (or in a $p\bar{p}$ atom in an $S$ state) into pions.

(a) Show that a $\pi^0\pi^0$ state cannot be produced by strong interactions.

*I know that a way to do this is to show that the interaction is not symmetric under parity, but am not sure how to go about doing that.*

(b) Show that the decay into a $\pi^+\pi^-$ final state is possible from a $^3S_1$ state, but not from a $^1S_0$ state. (Here we use the spectroscopic notation $^{2S+1}L_J$.) Consider $C$, $P$, and $CP$, where $C$ is the charge conjugation operator, and $P$ is the parity operator.

*I don't even know what "spectroscopic notation" is.*

Comment: noidea  has given you this link  http://www.personal.soton.ac.uk/ab1u06/teaching/phys3002/course/20_PCCP.pdf in a deleted answer, saying : Try to read first few pages from this link, I think this might help a bit,