# Proton and Antiproton decaying into positive and negative pions

Tags: homework-and-exercises, particle-physics, nuclear-physics

A proton and an antiproton annihilate at rest (or in a $p\bar{p}$ atom in an S state) into pions.

Show that the decay into a $\pi^+\pi^-$ final state is possible from a $^3S_1$ state, but not from a $^1S_0$ state. (Here we use the spectroscopic notation $^{2S+1}L_J$.) Consider C, P, and CP, where C is the charge conjugation operator, and P is the parity operator.

I deduced that $P_{\pi^+\pi^-}=1$ and $C_{\pi^+\pi^-}=1$, and that $P_{p\bar{p}}=-1$, $C_{p\bar{p}}=-1$ for $S=1$ and $C_{p\bar{p}}=1$ for $S=0$.

It does not seem like the proposal given in the problem is true, given what I found, so I am not sure where I have gone wrong and how to proceed.

Note: I asked this question already, but cannot edit it. I have made a better attempt.

Comment: Hi there! If you're not able to edit your [other question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/506468/44126) into the form that you want, let's fix that problem rather than asking another one. Cast a moderator flag if you would like help from us.

Comment: @rob  it is not an exact dublicate, only the title is, the content differs a lot. Maybe the one left could be made the duplicate, as the OP wanted, he/she  just rewrote because for  some reason could not edit, he/she says.